AUC for a seaborn distplot kde with multiple curves
sorry if this is a very silly question, but I've been trying to understand how to calculate the area under each curve of a seaborn distplot where i use common_norm=False. I understand that in this case, there is a form of normalization performed and that the sum of the areas under each curve should be 1. My problem is that i don't seem to figure out how to calculate the area under each curve from the values of the kde. I have 3 curves, one for which the kde has a high peak, one for which it has a very low peak and one for which it is bimodal. Intuitively, these areas should be different, but from what i do, i get the same result for each area which seems to be wrong.
my code would be something like this (the data is different, but has a similar shape):
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps

np.random.seed(0)
low_peak_data = np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=0.5, size=100)
high_peak_data = np.random.normal(loc=7, scale=0.5, size=300)
bimodal_data = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(loc=9, scale=0.5, size=200), 
                           np.random.normal(loc=11, scale=0.5, size=100)))
data = np.concatenate((low_peak_data, high_peak_data, bimodal_data))
labels = ['Low Peak', 'High Peak', 'Bimodal']

sns.displot(data, kde=True)

groups = {'Low Peak': low_peak_data, 'High Peak': high_peak_data, 'Bimodal': bimodal_data}

areas = []
for name, group_data in groups.items():
  kde = sns.kdeplot(group_data, shade=True)
  kde_lines = kde.get_lines()[0]
  x_kde, y_kde = kde_lines.get_data()
  area = simps(y_kde, x_kde)
  areas.append(area)
  print(f"Area under {name} KDE curve: {area}")

sum_area = sum(areas)

for name, area in zip(labels, areas):
  norm_area = area / sum_area
  print(f"Normalized area under {name} KDE curve: {norm_area}")`


https://stackoverflow.com/a/72653612/7758804 show how to calculate the area under the curve.

The lines kde = sns.kdeplot(group_data, shade=True) and kde_lines = kde.get_lines()[0] show some misunderstandings:

sns.kdeplot() returns the subplot (ax) onto which everything is drawn. In this case, it is the same subplot that was created with sns.displot(). Seaborn follows a logic of being a visualization library, it won't return calculations.
with shade=True no lines are created, but a colored polygon.
kde.get_lines()[0] always gets the same line because seaborn keeps adding to the same subplot. In your case, you get the curve created by sns.displot, while the filled polygons created by the calls to sns.kdeplot are very small compared to the result of sns.displot.

By default, sns.displot uses a "count" statistic. This is a regular histogram with the height of each bar equal to the number of values inside the x-range of that bar. A kde curve is adapted by rescaling it so that its area equals the area of the histogram.  With a "count" statistic, common_norm is ignored, as each subset is rescaled to the area of its corresponding histogram, which doesn't depend on the other subsets.
The area of one bar is its width (measured on the x-axis) times its height (the number of input values that belong to that bar).  As each input value goes into exactly one bar, the sum of all the bar heights is equal to the number of input values.  As such, the area of the histogram is the width of the bars (which should be equal for all bars) times the number of input values.
By default, the kde-curve is cut-off to the width of the histogram.  The area of that reduced kde-curve is a bit lower than the area of the curve if it would go on infinitely.  Setting cut=3 makes the curves go a bit further than the default.
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps

np.random.seed(0)
low_peak_data = np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=0.5, size=100)
high_peak_data = np.random.normal(loc=7, scale=0.5, size=300)
bimodal_data = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(loc=9, scale=0.5, size=200),
                               np.random.normal(loc=11, scale=0.5, size=100)))
data = np.concatenate((low_peak_data, high_peak_data, bimodal_data))
labels = ['Low Peak', 'High Peak', 'Bimodal']
groups = {'Low Peak': low_peak_data, 'High Peak': high_peak_data, 'Bimodal': bimodal_data}

g = sns.displot(data=groups, kde=True, stat='count', common_norm=False, kde_kws={'cut': 3})
ax = g.ax  # when g is a facetgrid with only one subplot, g.ax points to that subplot
for label, curve, bars in zip(labels[::-1], ax.lines, ax.containers):
    x_kde, y_kde = curve.get_data()
    area = simps(y_kde, x_kde)
    bar_width = bars[0].get_width()
    print(f'{label}: Calculated area = {area:.6f}')
    print(f'  Expected area: bar_width * count = {bar_width:.6f} * {len(groups[label])} = {bar_width * len(groups[label]):.6f}')


Output:
Bimodal: Calculated area = 158.753764
  Expected area: bar_width * count = 0.529179 * 300 = 158.753767
High Peak: Calculated area = 158.753767
  Expected area: bar_width * count = 0.529179 * 300 = 158.753767
Low Peak: Calculated area = 52.917922
  Expected area: bar_width * count = 0.529179 * 100 = 52.917922

With the "density" statistic, the kde curve gets its default area, namely 1. The corresponding histogram is also rescaled to get an area of 1. With common_norm=False all groups are displayed independently, each with an area of 1.
g = sns.displot(data=groups, kde=True, stat='density', common_norm=False, kde_kws={'cut': 3})
ax = g.ax
for label, curve in zip(labels[::-1], ax.lines):
    x_kde, y_kde = curve.get_data()
    area = simps(y_kde, x_kde)
    print(f'{label}: Calculated area = {area:.6f}')
    print(f'  Expected area: {1:.6f}')


Output:
Bimodal: Calculated area = 1.000000
  Expected area: 1.000000
High Peak: Calculated area = 1.000000
  Expected area: 1.000000
Low Peak: Calculated area = 1.000000
  Expected area: 1.000000

With the "density" statistic, but common_norm=True, the area of the histograms of the combined groups totals 1. Each group gets scaled down to the proportion it has in the total.
g = sns.displot(data=groups, kde=True, stat='density', common_norm=True, kde_kws={'cut': 3})
ax = g.ax
for label, curve in zip(labels[::-1], ax.lines):
    x_kde, y_kde = curve.get_data()
    area = simps(y_kde, x_kde)
    print(f'{label}: Calculated area = {area:.6f}')
    print(f'  Expected area: group_count / total_count = {len(groups[label])} / {len(data)} = {len(groups[label]) / len(data):.6f}')


Output:
Bimodal: Calculated area = 0.428571
  Expected area: group_count / total_count = 300 / 700 = 0.428571
High Peak: Calculated area = 0.428571
  Expected area: group_count / total_count = 300 / 700 = 0.428571
Low Peak: Calculated area = 0.142857
  Expected area: group_count / total_count = 100 / 700 = 0.142857

